# Validation rule to prohibit several words in a text field

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

I am looking for a validation rule (to prevent coding) that prohibits certain words (in my case Department names in a Contact FirstName field)

I want the list to be easily maintainable, so I hoped to do it with a Custom Metadata.  However this is not accessible in Validation Rules, so we changed to a comma separated list in a Custom Label (with a leading and trailing , .

`CONTAINS(LOWER($Label.Excluded_Department_Names),',' & TRIM(LOWER(FirstName)) & ',')`

But this is just not exactly what I want...
If my list contains a department like "marketing", I would also want to prohibit marketingdept or marketinguser.

So, my list contains entire prohibited words and my field contains "at least" a word from that list.
Do you have a suggestion, or should we move to Apex instead?

Thanks!

Marc

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for the REGEX function (see the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) and search "REGEX").

You need to change your label to be of the form:

```
word1|word2|word3|word4
```

Your validation is then:

```
REGEX(TheFieldToCheck__c, $Label.Excluded_Department_Names)
```

If you also need the `FirstName` piece, you can add that via string concatenation, separating it from the other words using pipe ("|").

Comment: Hi Phil, Thanks!  I will test this...!